# Optimal way to loop through a range in a defined order (start at the middle)

Tags: java, for-loop

I want to loop through a defined range but the order is important to me.
Lets say I'm at the position 20, and I want to go from 20 to 30 and afterwards from 20 backwards to 10.
My code at the moment is:

```
Object nextElement = currentElement.next();
for (int i= 20; i<= 30; i++) {
    if (nextElement == null) {
        break;
    }
    if (!isCondition(nextElement,i)) {
        continue;
    }
    nextElement.runSomething();
    nextElement = nextElement.next();
}

Object previousElement = currentElement.previous();
for (int i= 20; i>= 10; i--) {
    if (previousElement == null) {
        break;
    }
    if (!isCondition(previousElement ,i)) {
        continue;
    }
    previousElement .runSomething();
    previousElement = previousElement.previous();
}
```

My problem with this is, I run 90% the same code on both loops. the numbers are not useful to geht the elements, they are just for counting. Is there a easyier way to do this?

Update: I forgot an important part! The duplicate code will manipulate the loop

Comment: well, seeing as you're not using the numbers, just do i=0;i<10 for both...?

Comment: Refactor the 90% same code to a method and call it in the for loop?

Comment: Do you use the value of i in the //do something part? Or is it only for the number of iterations?

Comment: Can you show what those elements are? You have declared them as Object but you call `next` on them so they are something else...

Comment: I need the numbers for the iteration, I use the backwards-iteration because I need to stop before zero and also there is a maximum number (the starting point at 20 was just an example). Aaaand if you're interested, the element is a gwt dom element ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
int[] indices = { 20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10};

for (int i : indices) {
  // loop body
}
```

Or of course you could build the list of indices:

```
List<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i=20 ; i<=30 ; i++) indices.add(i);
for (int i= 20; i>=10; i--) indices.add(i);

for (int i : indices) {
  // loop body
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function for the loop and the "do something":

```
public void doSomething(Object element, int pos) {
  ...
}

public void myloop(Object nextElement, Object previousElement) {
    for (int i = 20; i <= 30; i++) {
        doSomething(nextElement, i);
        nextElement = nextElement.next();
    }
    for (int i = 20; i <= 30; i++) {
        doSomething(previousElement, i);
        previousElement = previousElement.previous();
    }
}
```

If you don't need the position in `doSomething` you can get rid of it. Also if you need to do different things in the first and second loop, create an other function, `doSomething2`

Comment: if op does different things in the loops, whats the point of using `doSomething()` and `doSomething2()` methods?

Comment: I mean different in the first and second but always the same in all the first loop and always the same in all the second loop. For example `registerNextElement(..)` and `registerPrevElement(..)`

Comment: Although if he wants to do different things every time then he could/should use callback style processing

Comment: yeah you probably right, seems to be the least duplicate code for this issue.